# htaccess change a query string name & value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to fathom this out for a little while and can't seem to come to a conclusion that always works.

I just need to replace a query string name see:

```
index.php?option=com_hikashop&ctrl=checkout&task=notify%C2%ACif_payment=bf_rbsbusinessgateway&componentStyle=common
```

we get the above which is the part I need to manipulate there are more query strings attached about 5-10 dependant.

I just need to change the section:

```
task=notify%C2%ACif_payment
```

to:

```
&task=notify&notif_payment
```

Can any mod rewrite experts provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?(task=notify)\%C2\%AC(if_payment)&?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2&not%3%4 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.